# Systemback Live Image

Tags: live-usb, backup, clone, live-environment

I just used Systemback utility to create a live image of my 14.04 installation. I added the "include user data files" option.

Now, my installation is over 100Gb, but the generated image was just under 10Gb, so I imagine something would have been excluded.

I booted the pendrive with this live system, and in fact I discovered the live system included all the packages installed with the package manager, and another thing or two (e.g. chrome browser), but lacked some important things, for example my Dropbox folder, my numpy/scipy (Anaconda) distribution and all the IDEs (NetBeans, IDEA, Android studio, etc..).

Why this happened? And if there is no workaround, may you suggest some other utility to generate a **complete** live system image?

Comment: What have you checked under the Exclude option in the main menu?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. I wanted to include all.

Comment: What version systemback are you using?  I've used it many times, and it worked all the time.

Comment: It should be the current version: Right now I cannot chack, but I installed it a couple of days ago from its PPA (ppa:nemh/systemback)..

Comment: If I manage to get it properly working, It could be a terrific utility, way superior to clonezilla & co. as a tool for moving a system installation..

Comment: I'm trying an image on a different machine now, when done I'll let you know.  But as I said I've never had a problem with it, and yes its far more superior than clonezilla.  Oh, I'm running version 1.4.110

Comment: Ignoring this issue for a moment, how I manage to install the systemback live system? Shall I install and include ubiquity? Is there any command line option?

Comment: by the way, I'm using version 1.4.110 as well.. Strange.. Is there any option in the settings panel I should check??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23994/discussion-between-mitch-and-madhatter).

Comment: Replied in chat. Sorry, I was out. Thanks for your help!